# Listview Items not getting displayed when converting XML Layout to bitmap image

Tags: android, xml, listview, bitmap

I've been trying to convert an XML Layout to bitmap image. When i click on the convert button, image is being generated. But my ListView items are not getting displayed. How can i do that?
Following is my code

```
mView = findViewById(R.id.f_view);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        mView.layout(0, 0, mView.getMeasuredWidth(), mView.getMeasuredHeight());
        mView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());
            mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Expense Calculator" + File.separator + "Expense.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                Toast.makeText(null, getApplicationContext()+ "Image Generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                fo.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            //finish();
        }
    }
```

and my xml code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include android:id="@+id/f_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        layout="@layout/view_expense"
        android:layout_above="@id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cimage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What should i do to get my listview items displayed? Can Someone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable drawing cache only when you want to get Bitmap from on-click.

```
  mView.buildDrawingCache(true);
```

Remove above line form `onCreate()` methdod.

You Need to disable `DrawingCache`  immediately after generating Bitmap from View 
like below code:

```
mView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Try Below onClick Code:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            mView.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());
            mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Expense Calculator" + File.separator + "Expense.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                Toast.makeText(null, getApplicationContext()+ "Image Generated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                fo.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            //finish();
        }
```

Use Below method to get bitmap from view you can pass view in this method :

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),   view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
view.draw(canvas);
return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: why one should create another Bitmap instead of compressing the one returned by getDrawingCache()?

Comment: Jobish want to store that bitmap into Storage .

Comment: I mean, can't you call compress on the Bitmap returned from the View?

Comment: I have tried this. But I'm not getting the Listview.

Comment: do you want to get bitmap of whole Listview or its Child.

Comment: I need to get the whole listview

Comment: Even a part of the listview is also fine for me

Comment: How could i do that? Can you please explain? When I'm trying it, i'm getting it forcely closed

Comment: use it within  onClick(View v) {}

Comment: Which means the remaining code in the on click method is not needed right?

Comment: Yes But if you want to save that bitmap then you need to add code for storage .

Comment: Ya ok. But getBitmapFromView(View view) { is showing error.

Comment: It is showing remove invalid modifiers. if i try to change it to the suggested correction, still the error exists. What should i do with this getBitmapFromView(View view) {???

Comment: @Chetan Can you please update this? But getBitmapFromView(View view) { is showing error. It is showing remove invalid modifiers. if i try to change it to the suggested correction, still the error exists. What should i do with this getBitmapFromView(View view) {???

Comment: Have passed mView in getBitmapFromView() method,

Comment: means have you passed `listview` object in `getBitmapFromView()` method.

Comment: @Chetan I did it like this                                                                                    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getWidth(),   mView.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
      mView.layout(0, 0, mView.getLayoutParams().width, mView.getLayoutParams().height);
      mView.draw(canvas);